Why windows hyper-v GVM use strorvsc & netvsc but not use standard virtio-scsi & virtio-net
Checked that windows gvm will storvsc and netvsc to implement sorage & network virtulization.
Why don't use virtio standard solutions. AFAIK, storvsc and virtio-scsi are all based on the scsi virtulizations.
Any benefit compare with vsc and virtio solutions?
